# django dynamic forms - Dynamic ChoiceField

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-models

In django, how can I make a selectible formField to access the db for every time it is being calld?
Right now the line : 
`status = forms.ChoiceField(choices=FormsTools.StatusesToTuples(Status.objects.all()))`
is executed once django is loaded and not every time the form is being showed.
How can I make the field dynamic ? so every time the form is being showed the selectible field will have values from db?

UPDATE:
POST data:

```
.
status: u'4'
.
.
```

in the Model, the field looks like this: `status = models.IntegerField()`

The View:

```
def edit_call(request, call_id):
    c = Call.objects.get(id=call_id)
    if request.POST:
        form = CallForm(request.POST, instance=c)
        print form.errors
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/ViewCalls/')

    else:
        form = CallForm(instance=c)
        args = {}
        args.update(csrf(request))
        args["form"] = form
        args["id"] = call_id

        t = get_template('edit_call.html')
        cont = RequestContext(request, args)
        html = t.render(cont)
        return HttpResponse(html)
```

The form:
simple as:

```
class CallForm (forms.ModelForm):

    employee_id = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Employee.objects.all())
    status = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Status.objects.all())
    class Meta():
        model = Call
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to call the contructor each time you load the form to update the choices. So the form should be:

```
class CallForm(forms.ModelForm): 
    ...
    status = forms.ChoiceField()

    def __init__(self, data=None, files=None, auto_id='id_%s', prefix=None,
                 initial=None, error_class=ErrorList, label_suffix=None,
                 empty_permitted=False):
        super(CallForm, self).__init__(data, files, auto_id, prefix, initial, error_class,
                                       label_suffix, empty_permitted)
        self.fields['status'].choices = FormsTools.StatusesToTuples(Status.objects.all())
```

Comment: I cant make it work. can you add a reference / tutorial / docs of what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [forms.ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield)?

UPDATED ANSWER FOLLOWING UPDATED QUESTION:

You now need to get your models and your forms to match:

Your model has an IntegerField, your form has a ModelChoiceField. The latter returns a pk string, not an integer ID.

Given that you're using a modelform, why not just let it do the work of creating the fields for you?

```
class CallForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Call
        fields = ('employee', 'status')  # assuming these are what the field names are
```

Comment: After changing it to `status = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Status.objects.all())` , submitting the form raising `ValueError ` of `value must be an integer.`.. How can it be fixed?

Comment: You need to show us (via an updated question) what the form is sending (ie, request.POST)

Comment: I think you need to show is a bit more - the whole post (with fake data if need be) and the view. How are you binding request.POST to your form?

Comment: hang on, show us your form too -- it's an IntegerField that's failing, not a ModelChoice field. The question's changed significantly :)

Comment: I dont think there is anything wrong with the form, it is really simple. Updated.

Comment: but where the selectible list comes ?

Comment: From the ModelForm - it knows how to create and populate the appropriate widgets

Comment: but the data comes from another model... :)

Comment: Ah, in that case I missed that in the original question. Why isn't the status field an FK to the Status model? Are you denormalizing the data early on?